# How to style emails?

Tags: css, email

Do I need to use style attribute everywhere, which leads to lots of duplication?

```
<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Some text</p>
```

Use of `<style>` seems to fail

Comment: why you not using a class atribute (asign it all same blocks)?

Comment: assuming you're talking about email/e-shot design, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many email clients will strip out CSS and classes, and one of the ways to ensure your content gets through is to use `inline-css`. As pointed out, this is time consuming and a pain to maintain.

Fortunately the kind people over at [mail chimp](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css) have developed a CSS Inliner tool.

So you can develop your email using CSS classes as you normally would, paste the html in to the tool, and receive correctly inlined CSS, perfect for emailing.

Takes a bit of tweaking and you need to declare everything, but it definitely does make life easier.

(e.g you have to declare font family, size and colour for `p, h1, h2, h3, td, ul` rather than just `body`, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use style, but if you want it to be available for all of the email clients I can  suggest you to use `<font size="2" color="red"><b>Some text</b></font>`

Answer (score 0):

use direct 'style' attribute for all tags, like teneff said in one of the answers here: 'not all email clients support full featured html'

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to used the

Here is a complete guide:

[HTML Email CSS Guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/%22HTML%20Email%20CSS%20Guide%22)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Check my Answer above. I have posted a link which contains a table with all the email clients and what CSS they support or don't support.